# object -> treeview -> selected object in my object

Tags: .net, treeview

Ok here is my question:

f.ex I have data structure something like this:

```
String name
  - List<String> subNames;
        - List<String> subSubNames;
```

I can easily populate tree view with the data. 
But how I should get vise versa stuff on this.

for example: 
I select some subSubName in the treeview, what is the easiest way to get Name, but not in the treeview it self but my own object.

I can code it by myself, but maybe there is an easiest way of doing that? Something like bind object to the treeview etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Tag` property of `TreeNode` to store data about the node.

An example where variable `name` contains your data and `treeView1` is your TreeView:

```
TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
node.Text = name.ToString(); //can be any string
node.Tag = name;
treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
```

To retrieve the data from a node, just cast the `Tag` to the right class:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    name = (Name)e.Node.Tag;
}
```